# Moyal products of exponentials

Tags: harmonic-analysis, quantum-mechanics, moyal-product

I have trouble verifying a claim made by Sharan in his paper: https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.20.414.

What he essentially claims is that the sequence of Moyal $*$-products

$$\underbrace{\exp(-itH/n)*\exp(-itH/n)*...*\exp(-itH/n)}_{n \;\textrm{products}}\tag{1}$$

converges to

$$\exp^*(-itH)\equiv\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f^{*k}}{k!},\quad 
\underbrace{f^{*k} = f* f* ... *f}_{k\; \textrm{products}}$$

The justification he gives is that $\exp^*(-itH/n)$ differs from $\exp(-itH/n)$ by a factor of $\mathcal{O}(1/n^2)$, but I don't know how to verify this.

I tried proving it in a different way, using the fact that $\exp^*(-itH)$ is the unique solution to the equation

$$\partial_t F_t = -iH*F_t,\quad F_0 = 1. \tag{2}$$

The idea here is to define the sequence $F_{t,n} = \underbrace{\exp(-itH/n)*\exp(-itH/n)*...*\exp(-itH/n)}_{n \;\textrm{products}}$. By taking its derivative and rescaling the time variable $t\rightarrow (n+1)t/n$, we get

$$\partial_t F_{t,n+1} = -\frac{i(n+1)}{n}\left(H e^{-itH/n}\right)*F_{t,n}.\tag{3}$$

If $F_{t,n}$ converges, then it satisfies $(2)$, and by uniqueness the limit of $(1)$ is equal to $\exp^*(-itH)$. However, I don't know how to prove convergence.

Any help would by nice!